# How to fit svg path into svg viewbox in React Native

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I am trying to implement barcode scanner viewFinder and I want to use svg icon to make it look nice, but I have a problem with forcing the path element inside the svg to take up the full svg width and height. I am using react native and to generate icon i use SVGR https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true&typescript=true in the scan handler I set the dimensions of the svg like so:

```
  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data, bounds }: BarCodeEvent) => {
    if (!bounds) return;
    const { origin, size } = bounds;
    setX(origin.x);
    setY(origin.y);
    setWidth(size.width);
    setHeight(size.height);
  };
```

and the I ise them inside the svg which looks like so

```
import * as React from "react";
import Svg, { SvgProps, Path } from "react-native-svg";

export const ViewFinder = (props: SvgProps & { top: number; left: number }) => {
  const { width, height, top, left } = props;
  return (
    <Svg
      width={width}
      height={height}
      style={{
        borderColor: "green",
        borderWidth: 2,
        position: "absolute",
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
      }}
      fill="none"
      stroke="green"
      preserveAspectRatio="none"
      viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}
    >
      <Path d="M6.13 1L6 16a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h15"></Path>
      <Path d="M1 6.13L16 6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v15"></Path>
    </Svg>
  );
};
```

original icon is a featerIcons crop icon https://feathericons.com/ and the original code of the icon is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-crop"><path d="M6.13 1L6 16a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h15"></path><path d="M1 6.13L16 6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v15"></path></svg>
```

as you can see I set the border color and borderWidth on the svg itself, and it scales to fit the container so here everything seems to be ok. I have viewBox and preserveAspectRatio set up its just the inner path not scaling with the svg, and it is not just this icon I have tries several and the issue is still this same so there must be something wrong with my understanding of svg.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: yes! thanks it worked :) I've set it to 0 0 24 24 (intrinsic) and it takes up the desired space thank you @Robert Longson !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally a viewBox would be 4 fixed numbers, i.e. unrelated to width and height. That should give you the result you want.

Your content doesn't change in size so your viewBox shouldn't change either.

Comment: To further clarify, the viewBox sets the scale that the internal vector data is using.  It's this relative to the data you have and should very rarely be changed.  (Occasionally I hack it slightly to better center the image or something.)  width and height are how the svg renders in its parent.  Usually pixels or percentage.